# Multi-wire branch circuit

Tags: wiring

I have a long distance from my breaker cabinet to my basement.  I ran a 12/3 with ground to the basement. Now I would like to add some outlets. Can I do as shown in image? or do I need to run 3 wires to each outlet?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawing as-done is fine.

Breakers will need to be a 2-pole 240V breaker, or two breakers with  an official, UL listed handle tie.  There must be 240V across the two hot legs, a duplex/twin breaker won't do.

Any recent Code will require GFCI protection. This can happen at the breaker or at the first receptacle in each string.

AFCI protection may be required in the most recent Codes, that must be at the breaker and will intersect with the 2-pole/handle tie requirement.